# XOR function differences between Python 3 and Python 2?

Tags: python, xor

Running in IDLE, Python 3.6.5 and Python 2.7.15 I have a strange problem with XOR. I get the correct answer with Python 2.7, and rubbish with Python 3.6. The Python 3.6 and 2.7 are not agreeing on a simple XOR. This is not an IDLE issue, since the behavior is the same in cygwin.

```
>>> ciphertext

'466d06ece998b7a2fb1d464fed2ced7641ddaa3cc31c9941cf110abbf409ed39598005b3399ccfafb61d0315fca0a314be138a9f32503bedac8067f03adbf3575c3b8edc9ba7f537530541ab0f9f3cd04ff50d66f1d559ba520e89a2cb2a83'
```

Python 2.7

```
>>> ciphertext.decode('hex')
'Fm\x06\xec\xe9\x98\xb7\xa2\xfb\x1dFO\xed,\xedvA\xdd\xaa<\xc3\x1c\x99A\xcf\x11\n\xbb\xf4\t\xed9Y\x80\x05\xb39\x9c\xcf\xaf\xb6\x1d\x03\x15\xfc\xa0\xa3\x14\xbe\x13\x8a\x9f2P;\xed\xac\x80g\xf0:\xdb\xf3W\\;\x8e\xdc\x9b\xa7\xf57S\x05A\xab\x0f\x9f<\xd0O\xf5\rf\xf1\xd5Y\xbaR\x0e\x89\xa2\xcb*\x83'
>>> for x, y in zip(ciphertext.decode('hex'), ' '*10):
    print "ord(x): " + chr(ord(x))
    print "ord(y): " + chr(ord(y))
    print(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)))


ord(x): F
ord(y):  
f
ord(x): m
ord(y):  
M
ord(x): 
ord(y): 
&
ord(x): ì
ord(y):  
Ì
ord(x): é
ord(y):  
É
ord(x): ˜
ord(y):  
¸
ord(x): ·
ord(y):  
—
ord(x): ¢
ord(y):  
‚
ord(x): û
ord(y):  
Û
ord(x): 
ord(y):  
=
```

Python 3.6

```
 >>> bytes.fromhex(ciphertext)

   b'Fm\x06\xec\xe9\x98\xb7\xa2\xfb\x1dFO\xed,\xedvA\xdd\xaa<\xc3\x1c\x99A\xcf\x11\n\xbb\xf4\t\xed9Y\x80\x05\xb39\x9c\xcf\xaf\xb6\x1d\x03\x15\xfc\xa0\xa3\x14\xbe\x13\x8a\x9f2P;\xed\xac\x80g\xf0:\xdb\xf3W\\;\x8e\xdc\x9b\xa7\xf57S\x05A\xab\x0f\x9f<\xd0O\xf5\rf\xf1\xd5Y\xbaR\x0e\x89\xa2\xcb*\x83'
>>> for x, y in zip(bytes.fromhex(ciphertext), ' '*10):
    print("x: ", chr(x))
    print("ord(y): ", chr(ord(y)))
    print(chr(x^ord(y)))


x:  F
ord(y):   
f
x:  m
ord(y):   
M
x:  
ord(y):   
&
x:  ì
ord(y):   
Ì
x:  é
ord(y):   
É
x:  
ord(y):   
¸
x:  ·
ord(y):   
<- different value
x:  ¢
ord(y):   
<- different value
x:  û
ord(y):   
Û
x:  
ord(y):   
=

In a cygwin window I get the following:
$ ./python2_test.py
Fm▒阷▒▒FO▒,▒vAݪ<▒▒A▒
f▒▒Y▒R▒▒▒*▒▒▒9▒ϯ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒2P;▒g▒:▒▒W\;▒ܛ▒▒7SA▒▒<▒O▒
ord(x): F
ord(y):
f
ord(x): m
ord(y):
M
ord(x):
ord(y):
&
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x): ▒
ord(y):
▒
ord(x):
ord(y):
=
$ ./python3_test.py
b'Fm\x06\xec\xe9\x98\xb7\xa2\xfb\x1dFO\xed,\xedvA\xdd\xaa<\xc3\x1c\x99A\xcf\x11\n\xbb\xf4\t\xed9Y\x80\x05\xb39\x9c\xcf\xaf\xb6\x1d\x03\x15\xfc\xa0\xa3\x14\xbe\x13\x8a\x9f2P;\xed\xac\x80g\xf0:\xdb\xf3W\\;\x8e\xdc\x9b\xa7\xf57S\x05A\xab\x0f\x9f<\xd0O\xf5\rf\xf1\xd5Y\xbaR\x0e\x89\xa2\xcb*\x83'
x:  F
ord(y):
f
x:  m
ord(y):
M
x:
ord(y):
&
x:  ì
ord(y):
Ì
x:  é
ord(y):
É
x:  
ord(y):
¸
x:  ·
ord(y):
<- missing
x:  ¢
ord(y):
<- missing
x:  û
ord(y):
Û
x:
ord(y):
=
```

Any help in sorting this out, would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're seeing a problem of encoding. If you try to reproduce the steps printing numbers instead of chars, you'll see no difference. These are the scripts:

Python2:

```
ciphertext = '466d06ece998b7a2fb1d464fed2ced7641ddaa3cc31c9941cf110abbf409ed39598005b3399ccfafb61d0315fca0a314be138a9f32503bedac8067f03adbf3575c3b8edc9ba7f537530541ab0f9f3cd04ff50d66f1d559ba520e89a2cb2a83'

out1 = []
out2 = []
out3 = []
for x, y in zip(ciphertext.decode('hex'), ' '*10):
    out1.append(hex(ord(x)))
    out2.append(hex(ord(y)))
    out3.append(hex(ord(x) ^ ord(y)))
print out1
print out2
print out3
```

Python 3:

```
ciphertext = '466d06ece998b7a2fb1d464fed2ced7641ddaa3cc31c9941cf110abbf409ed39598005b3399ccfafb61d0315fca0a314be138a9f32503bedac8067f03adbf3575c3b8edc9ba7f537530541ab0f9f3cd04ff50d66f1d559ba520e89a2cb2a83'
out1 = []
out2 = []
out3 = []
for x, y in zip(bytes.fromhex(ciphertext), ' '*10):
    out1.append(x)
    out2.append(ord(y))
    out3.append(x ^ ord(y))
print(out1)
print(out2)
print(out3)
```

If you execute them both, you'll see that the output is the same.

You can see it directly on ideone, [python2](https://ideone.com/nUGae5) and [python3](https://ideone.com/uoQjSj)

EDIT: The execution of the script that I have given, slightly modified to show hex instead of raw numbers, give me as an output:

Python2:

```
['0x46', '0x6d', '0x6', '0xec', '0xe9', '0x98', '0xb7', '0xa2', '0xfb', '0x1d']
['0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20']
['0x66', '0x4d', '0x26', '0xcc', '0xc9', '0xb8', '0x97', '0x82', '0xdb', '0x3d']
```

Python3:

```
['0x46', '0x6d', '0x6', '0xec', '0xe9', '0x98', '0xb7', '0xa2', '0xfb', '0x1d']
['0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20', '0x20']
['0x66', '0x4d', '0x26', '0xcc', '0xc9', '0xb8', '0x97', '0x82', '0xdb', '0x3d']
```

With the same input data you gave, I have a different input but my output data are coherent between Python2 and Python3.

Comment: bracco23 - thanks for your prompt reply, but I am getting differences between the python 3 and python 2 xor's in my program.

Comment: bracco23 - thanks for your prompt reply, but I am getting differences between the python 3 and python 2 XOR's in my program. As an example: in python 2 I get the following: [66,c9,cd,29,19,19,80,12,d0,fc,8b,bf,f0,9a], which is correct,while in the python 3 XOR with the same data I get [66,c389,c38d,29,19,19,c280,12,c390,c3bc,c28b,c2bf,c3b0,c29a] which causes errors. I have no idea where hex values like 'c389' can come from in my data.

Comment: @JamOne I have edited the answer giving my output, which is the same between python2 and python3. If you can, edit your question and use a service like [ideone](https://ideone.com/) to share an executable [mcve] (don't forget to include the code in the question itself.)

Comment: once again many thanks for your patience. I have used the ideone service.

Comment: once again many thanks for your patience. I have used the ideone service. For the python 2.6 https://ideone.com/eIRNh8 for the python 3.4 https://ideone.com/0RLKUN essentially the very same code, with the minor differences between python 2 and 3, but I get very difference answers. For the 2.6 version, the first 10 bytes [66 4d 26 cc c9 b8 97 82 db 3d]. For the 3.4 version, the first 10 bytes [66 4d 26 c38c c389 c2b8 c297 c282 c39b 3d]. I simply cannot figure out why the difference, and it gives the wrong results in python 3.x

Comment: If you read the answer carefully, I propose that the problem is in the encoding `chr` does, because if you don't use it, it doesn't give any difference. In your new examples, if you return arrays instead of strings and print out hex values, you get the correct output. See [Python2](https://ideone.com/WQf54H) and [Python3](https://ideone.com/QdbaHI)